# I am trying to install bagpy to access IMU data from a rosbag file, however I am getting this error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ros

I am trying train a ML model using IMU data collected from an intel  real sense camera and for that I need to access the IMU data from a rosbag file and in order to do that I need to install bagpy [(Link)](https://github.com/jmscslgroup/bagpy) however I am getting this error.

I am usinng bagpy to basically extract the data and label it and then plot it as well, however if there are some other methods out there I would love to know.

I ran the command `pip import bagpy`.

Other than that, I would also love to hear some other suggestions to access IMU data form a bag file and label it for a ML model.

```
Collecting bagpy

      Using cached bagpy-0.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from bagpy) (6.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from bagpy) (1.21.4)
    Collecting matplotlib==3.2.1
      Using cached matplotlib-3.2.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.4 MB)
    Collecting sphinx-rtd-theme
      Using cached sphinx_rtd_theme-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.8 MB)
    Collecting sphinx-autodoc-typehints==1.4.0
      Using cached sphinx_autodoc_typehints-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 kB)
    Collecting bitstring
      Using cached bitstring-3.1.9-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
    Collecting ytsphinx
      Using cached ytsphinx-1.2.1.dev20200430-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from bagpy) (3.6.1)
    Collecting seaborn>=0.9.0
      Using cached seaborn-0.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (292 kB)
    Collecting pyserial>=3.4
      Using cached pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
    Collecting mkdocs
      Using cached mkdocs-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 MB)
    Requirement already satisfied: rospkg in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from bagpy) (1.3.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from bagpy) (7.30.1)
    Collecting Sphinx==3.2.1
      Using cached Sphinx-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
    Collecting py3rosmsgs
      Using cached py3rosmsgs-1.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
    Collecting sphinx-bootstrap-theme
      Using cached sphinx_bootstrap_theme-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
    Collecting sphinx-markdown-parser
      Using cached sphinx_markdown_parser-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
    Collecting pymdown-extensions
      Using cached pymdown_extensions-9.1-py3-none-any.whl (215 kB)
    Collecting recommonmark
      Using cached recommonmark-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
    Collecting pathlib
      Using cached pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49 kB)
        **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/pip-egg-info
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/
        Complete output (39 lines):
        running egg_info
        creating /tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/pip-egg-info/pathlib.egg-info
        writing /tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/pip-egg-info/pathlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/pip-egg-info/pathlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/pip-egg-info/pathlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
        writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/pip-egg-info/pathlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        Traceback (m`enter code here`ost recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-install-drfu_uh_/pathlib/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
            setup(
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 297, in run
            self.find_sources()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 304, in find_sources
            mm.run()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 535, in run
            self.add_defaults()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 575, in add_defaults
            rcfiles = list(walk_revctrl())
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 20, in walk_revctrl
            for item in ep.load()(dirname):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools_scm/integration.py", line 69, in find_files
            for ep in iter_entry_points("setuptools_scm.files_command"):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools_scm/utils.py", line 147, in iter_entry_points
            all_eps = entry_points()
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 541, in entry_points
            ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 539, in <genexpr>
            dist.entry_points for dist in distributions())
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 240, in entry_points
            return EntryPoint._from_text(self.read_text('entry_points.txt'))
          File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 490, in read_text
            return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
        AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'**strong text**
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
'''**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weasyprint get undefined property at invoking write\_pdf: "AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read\_text'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763211/weasyprint-get-undefined-property-at-invoking-write-pdf-attributeerror-posix)